# how do i copy/upload file from S3 to EC2 in PHP

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am having a file on S3 
         Example: test-company/upload/abc.txt
  I want to upload this abc.txt to my EC2 in php
  Do anybody having any idea please share it with example..

Answer (score 3):

I've used [amazon-s3-php-class](https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class) which works great.

Zend Framework also has [AWS support](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.amazon.s3.html) 
 though you can't use it with Europe until ZF 1.8.2 is released. (Due to a bug in 1.8.1 that has been fixed in svn now)

Comment: +1 for the amazon-s3-php-class. Works like an absolute charm.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a linux utility called [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd). I guess you could easily call this command line utility from PHP.

Comment: How can i call s3cmd from PHP code. i am trying to do it. but it does not works.

Comment: Here is an article about calling shell commands from PHP:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-commandline/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for the new Zend Framework (1.8) implementation. Haven't really checked it out yet but you can find it at [http://framework.zend.com/](http://framework.zend.com). Docs here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.amazon.s3.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no method to "upload to EC2" as it is an instance of a virtual server and not a storage service. You would need to put your own service on EC2 in order to upload to it.

You can, however, download from S3 to EC2. Simply run wget or similar on the EC2 instance to pull down the file from S3 bucket URL (with authentication if necessary).